# Browser does not support my own font in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, fonts

I want to embed my own font in my .aspx but google chrome and firefox doesn't support the font whereas IE supports the font. Let me know how to embed the font in asp.net page.

My code is ,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Font</title>

<style type="text/css">

.title
{
    @font-face 
{
    font-family: Mullai;
    src: url('F:\ASP\SAMP - Mullai.ttf')format("truetype");
}
}
</style>
</head>

</body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td style="width: 91px">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center" style="width: 351px" class="title">தமிழ்<br /></td>
<td style="width: 91px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

chrome and firefox doesn't calls the css class. Let me know whats the problem in it. Thanks in advance

Comment: The path here `src: url('F:\ASP\SAMP - Mullai.ttf')format("truetype");` is wrong. You should upload the font files in the server and use relative paths

Comment: @Tasos K  Is that browser cannot accept local path??

Comment: Yes, physical paths wont work most of the times.

Comment: But it works on internet explorer. And i tried after uploading the font in server also, it doesn't works. Is there is any format to dispaly in chrome or other browser??? Its an intranet application. I want to display the font in LAN systems.

Comment: See a sample here http://www.netavatar.co.in/2011/05/01/how-to-include-external-font-file-in-css-cross-browser-compatible/

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem before and it probably comes from the config file.